# jQuery UI Accordion (hiding all by default)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Hello I am using [jQuery UI Accodions](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion)

By default, the first accordion is shown and other are hidden. I would like to hide all the accordions by default until the user clicks it.

How do I do that ?

Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code should accomplish this

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: false });
```

Answer (score 7):

This is the updated code to accomplish the appropriate.

$( ".selector" ).accordion({active: false , collapsible: true});

Comment: Why is the `collapsible` argument required? Updated version? ifso what version?

Comment: by default collapsible is false.  so its the first accordion active. to hide all accordion we need to  set collapsible true

Comment: you don't need collapsible to be true to hide all of the tabs at the start.

@EWit BUT you do need collapsible to be true to collapse an open one, once any of them have been opened.

Answer (score 0):

"Setting active to false will collapse all panels. This requires the collapsible option to be true."
http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

Answer (score 0):

To hide all the accordion's panel by default, you need to set the following 2 options:

```
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true
  });
```

The **active** option specifies which panel is currently open. By default its value is 0, i.e the first panel.

The **collapsible** option specifies whether all the sections can be closed at once. Allows collapsing the **active** section.